# How to write database queries in helper in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 4. First I write this to get records from the database, but this shows me an error ( Call to a member function `table()` on null)

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI -> db -> select('*');
$CI -> db -> from($table_name);
```

Then I read from documentation and write this

```
$db->table("tablename");
```

But this method also failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Query Builder is loaded through the table() method on the database connection. This sets the FROM portion of the query for you and returns a new instance of the Query Builder class:

```
$db      = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('users');
//loading query builder

$output = $builder->table('table_name')
        ->get();
// Produces: SELECT * FROM table_name
```

To get result as array you can add one more line of code.

```
$output = $output->getResultArray();
```

For selecting particular fileds.

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('users');
//loading query builder

$output = $builder->table('table_name')
        ->select('filedname2, fieldname2, fieldname3,..')
        ->get();
$output = $output->getResultArray();
```

You can use where clause also for more details refer to codeigniter4 documentation page.
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 0):

```
//initialize database connection
$db  = \Config\Database::connect();

//created builder to get queries results
$builder = $db->table('users');

//select particular columns
$builder->select('id','first_name','last_name');

//if you want to select all columns
$builder->select('*')

//if you want to put where
$builder->where('id',1);

//if you want to put order by desc or asc
$builder->orderBy('id desc');

//get records
$output = $builder->get();

//if you want to return your results in array format then,
return $output->getResultArray();

//if you want to return your results in std object then,
return $output->getResult();
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32501287)